# Is there any significance to the choice of similes for poetry in "Some Like Poetry"?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, polish-language, wislawa-szymborska

The poem ["Some Like Poetry"](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/some-like-poetry/) by Polish writer Wislawa Szymborska is a musing lament about the unpopularity of poetry among the general population. The middle verse consists of a series of similes which compare liking poetry to liking various other things:

> but one also likes chicken soup with noodles,
>   one likes compliments and the color blue,
>   one likes an old scarf,
>   one likes having the upper hand,
>   one likes stroking a dog.

This *could* just be a random list of examples of things a person might like, but I'm hoping it's more carefully thought out than that.

**What, if anything, is the significance of this choice of "likes"?**